# How can I influence a repeatable, random sequence?

Tags: math, random, language-agnostic

I'm using a RNG with a fixed seed. Depending on the input, which is an arbitrary sequence of ints, I would like to influence the output. Something like this:

```
foreach (int i in source_int_sequence) {
    write_output (RNG.nextDouble());
    RNG.feed (i);
}
```

The feedback function should influence the next output in a way that is repeatable (same input creates same output) but difficult to predict (i.e. *random*).

The RNG is not assumed to be cryptographically secure, naturally the influenced result does not have to be either. Note, however, that the source sequence might look strange, i.e. only zeros, +1 and -1 alternating, steadily increasing numbers, or anything else you could think of that throws off a naive implementation.

I'm using C#, but I believe this question is language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can solve this is by turning your input sequence of integers into a sequence of seemingly random values.  Once you've done that, you can influence the random numbers generated by generating random numbers from the pseudorandom generator and then XORing them with the sequence of random numbers you're getting back.

One possible way to turn the input sequence into a random sequence would be to use a technique like [cipher-block chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) or [counter mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) on a block cipher.  This would give you back something cryptographically secure if the block cipher you use is secure (though, as you've mentioned, this is overkill).  Another option would be to use a [rolling hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) with an unbounded window size to build hash values out of the stream.

Hope this helps!